# Log4j2 with Websphere Application Server org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletContainerInitializer not a subtype

Tags: servlets, websphere, log4j2

We have an application which uses Log4j2 and running on WAS 8.5. We have selected the class loading option as PARENT_LAST, so the jar files will be picked up from WEB-INF/lib. We are error getting the below error when starting up the server.

```
com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: Failed to load webapp: javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer: Provider org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletContainerInitializer not a subtype
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:432)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:718)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1177)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1370)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:776)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$5.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2195)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5387)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5603)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2200)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:435)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:378)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:126)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:984)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:502)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1865)
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: Failed to load webapp: javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer: Provider org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletContainerInitializer not a subtype
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:759)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:634)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:426)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer: Provider org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletContainerInitializer not a subtype
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:176)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:749)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer: Provider org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletContainerInitializer not a subtype
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:243)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:193)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:381)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:457)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initializeServletContainerInitializers(WebAppImpl.java:535)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:409)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:169)
```

When we have the lo4j2 related jar's as part of the ext folder of the server, it is working fine without any issues. 
We also have log4j jar's as well as part of the application which is being used by some third party jar's. 
Can some throw some light as what is going on here and why this error is being thrown?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using web.xml for your application configuration refer to following link for configuring log4j-web module related listener and filter.

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have added the listener and filter has suggested in the log4j website. But I'm still getting the above error. Also, if I have the log4j related jar in the ext folder of WAS and use the class loader option as PARENT_FIRST, it is working without any issues. But I need to use PARENT_LAST to load my application jar's first.

Comment: This could be a classloader issue. I assume that your app is servlet3.0 app. Check your classpath to ensure that there are no servlet-api on your classpath and there are no dupllcate log4j2 jar files on the classpath.